# How to change EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

In django/contrib/admin/views/main.py, you can find:

```
# Text to display within change-list table cells if the value is blank.
EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE = ugettext_lazy('(None)')
```

How can I cange this value without the use of translations and without overriding the whole django-admin app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to monkey patch `EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE`. Try to put this on top of `settings.py`:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views import main
main.EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE = <your_value>
```

It doesn't look that nice but I hope it works for you.

Comment: Yes it does, quite nicely in fact. The problem here is that since this value is this lazy translation by default, it does not get caught by default or default_if_none filters. I had to override all admin templates (3 files) that use it, and insert a custom filter there. So this is a more concise solution that is more sustainable.

Comment: @Enuy great that this hacky way is simpler :)

Comment: I had to put it into the `admin.py`.