# How to make a default value in ForeignKey using User

Tags: python, django

I was going through "Django for Beginners", there is a project that make posts with title, author and body fields, u can add posts via admin where in author field u choose either -- or the admin itself, what I'd like to do is if this field is not edited then then its value would be a string that i can pass (i. e. in that case 'anon') . I've found a way to make a default for ForeignKey but without models.User so how to do it in that case?

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

def anon():
    return 'User.username="Anon"'    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        "auth.User", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=anon
    )
    
    body = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Firstly I've tried to plainly type in `author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",      on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='anon')`.

Then to make a function that would return the desired string, then looked up models.User fields and found username field, tried to return it in anon() but only got SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="? when entered makemigrations command

Comment: I'm seeing your question in a peer review. If the provided answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a callable that gets or creates the `User` with username `Anon` this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


def anon():
    User = get_user_model()
    usr, __ = User.objects.get_or_create(
        username='Anon', defaults={'password': ''}
    )
    return usr


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=anon
    )

    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

That being said, it is probably *not* a good idea to make an extra user: you can work with `None`/`NULL` to specify that there is no author. This is more efficient and will not impose any security risks if people for example manage to login with that anonymous user, so:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )

    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: ok, gotcha ya. Then is it possible when choosing null=True instead of '--' display 'anon'?

Comment: @KARL: you can specify this in the `ModelAdmin` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35003020/67579 as well as in (model)forms, and in templates with the [`|default_if_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) template filter.

Comment: thank u, although even going through ur link and some others I couldn't change the '--' to 'anon' in admin panel,  |default_if_none is what i really needed although couldn't formulate it from the 1st time